# Degree of dependence between individuals of a variable

Tags: correlation, random-variable, independence

I'd like to know if there is a measure that computes the dependence between individuals of an only variable. For example, let $X$ be such that $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, I'd like $dependence(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = something$.

Comment: What is dependence? Correlation? What are the $X$'s?

Comment: $X$ is a continuous variable. I can use a correlation or similar measure.

Comment: So you have a vector of continuous values and you would like to estimate something like correlation? So where is the issue?

Comment: From the definition, we need two variables to calculate the correlation. But I have only variable, and I'd like to estimate the relationship between the individuals of variable $X$. This is the problem.

Comment: You are thinking of autocorrelation then.